# cakephp static page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am learning cakephp and my installation is as follow

localhost/wordpress/cakephpapplication

now I created a basic page and in the elements I created the top navigation links. I wanted to create an About us page, so under pages folder, where I have my home.ctp page, I created a page called about.ctp. Then in elements top.ctp page I entered the link as

```
<li><a href="wordpress/pages/about">About Us</a></li>
```

and when I click it doesnt find the page. Then I tried this

```
<li><a href="/pages/about">About Us</a></li>
```

and that didnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/wordpress/cakephpapplication/pages/about
```

worked!

I wasn't defining the application in the path.